# QuerySelector returning Null from a classname - can you reference classname from content script in background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to queryselect a class created in my content.html in my background script. I keep getting a reference error whenever I use:
var div = document.querySelector(".row").cloneNode(true);

I gave it an ID, but that breaks the append loop by overwriting each var div. I want there to be a new div created each time.

Code from my Background Script

```js
        function appendData(data) {
          var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].productName === "HERA 2.0") {
              var div = document.querySelector(".row").cloneNode(true);
              price.innerHTML = data[i].productPrice;
              productTitle.innerHTML = data[i].productName;
              images.src = 'https://' + data[i].productImage;
              cart.href = data[i].productUrl;
              mainContainer.appendChild(div);
              console.log('div appended');
            }
          }
        }
        let data=[];
        appendData(data);
```

Code from my content page (HTML)

```html
<div id="myData">
  <div class="container page-wrapper">
    <div class="page-inner">
      <div class="row" id="row">
        <div class="el-wrapper" id="el-wrapper">
          <div class="box-up">
            <img id="images" src="">
            <div class="img-info">
              <div class="info-inner">
                <span id="productTitle"></span>
                <span class="p-company">Viasweat</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="box-down">
            <div class="h-bg">
              <div class="h-bg-inner"></div>
            </div>

            <a class="cart" id="cart" href="" target="_blank">
              <span class="price" id="price"></span>
              <span class="add-to-cart">
              <span class="txt">I want it!</span>
            </span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do "price", "productTitle", "images", and "cart" come from?

Comment: They're coming from my database - everything there works. I can put the code in but it's just a fetch.

Comment: Right but your code assigns to `price.innerHTML` — where is `price` defined?

Comment: Price is defined in the HTML file (reference: <span class="price" id="price"></span>)

Comment: Well JavaScript doesn't know that. The "id" attributes must be **unique** also; you can't use the same id value more than once.

Comment: I think the challenge now is that when I clone, I keep cloning the original ID. I don't know how to get it so that it won't keep overwriting each other.